# XAMPP - PHP Stopped Working After Being Copied

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I created a website with multiple tables in phpMyAdmin, multiple pages and files (html, php, jquery, javascript, css) using XAMPP.

I saved all my files within the htdocs folder in the XAMPP folder, and I created a .htaccess file with:

> *RemoveHandler .html .htm*
>
> *AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm*

and other lines in it (that do not interfere with these two lines in any way.
I have tried with and without these two lines.

I am new to XAMPP.

When creating all the files and pages for the website, everything ran perfect. I finished the website. However, once I copied the file (which contains XAMPP and all my website files) to our server, PHP won't run. It won't run off the server, and it won't run off the computer where the files are stored.

HTML files comment out some of the PHP, other PHP is written to the webpage as content
PHP files displays all the PHP code

**PHP was running fine until I copied the folder containing XAMPP**

I used <?php to begin files (not shortened <?) and ?> to close files.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you copy the whole XAMPP over to your server? If so, there's your problem. Just copy the contents of the XAMPP htdocs folder to the proper folder on your server. The location on your server will depend on your server but some likely options include: the root, public_html, or a folder with the same name as the domain.

Comment: I originally copied the entire XAMPP folder over, however I removed it once it stopped working and downloaded XAMPP on the server and then copied the files over, I am still getting the same issue. I placed all my files in the htdocs so that php would run them, and I added the lines written above to treat html files as php, and in all files php doesn't run.


I made test pages (html and php). The html with PHP in it displays nothing (php is commented out unless in an input's value field). The php pages just show the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm...well when i want to copy my projects from my laptop to another y only copy the directory where i save my project....my way is to install a new xampp in the computer where i want to copy and then y go to...

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/(find your project directory and copy the entire directory)
```

go and paste in the same rute in the new xampp in te other computer

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/(here you paste your work)
```

Then you can export your tables from xampp and load the file into the new xampp...for trying your install let's put xampp some testing stuffs

copy this into a new project and create a file as index

copy this

```
<div>
<h3 align="center"><strong align="center">Bienvenido</strong></h3>
<table align="left" width="50px">
    <tr>
        <td width="20px">
            <h3 align="right" style="font-size:18px"><strong align="center">Bienvenido 1</strong></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3 align="left" style="font-size:18px">hola 1</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20px">
            <h3 align="right" style="font-size:18px"><strong align="center">Bienvenido 2</strong></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3 align="left" style="font-size:18px">Hola 2</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>   

</table> 
<?php echo "hoja de pruebaaaaaa";?>
```

try this adn see what happens...

Comment: Thank you for the quick response I'll try that see how it works!

Comment: I just finished trying this as well, downloaded XAMPP and copied files over, I seem to still get the same issue. I originally downloaded XAMPP (as well as the download I just tried) - V. 1.8.3, with only default modules (PHP and Apache I believe) as well as phpMyAdmin and mysql. I don't need Tomcat or any of the other modules.

I am still baffled :/

Comment: mmm i can't figure it out what's wrong if you are installing a new xammp in the other computer and copy only de directory of the project...try to install as default the xampp with all it's components adn follow the steps and comment if it works, i will be attentive with your problem ok?

Comment: Sounds good I'll try that and see what happens.

My boss and I have been trying all morning to fix this, if we figure it out I'll post it here

Thanks again

Comment: hey, i found this, it helps me when i tried to configure my xampp for the first time, maybe you are skipping a step or something like that check out... [http://es.wikihow.com/configurar-un-servidor-web-personal-con-XAMPP]

Comment: Just checked that out and tried it, it still doesn't seem to work. Status and everything is exactly as it should be... And this is funny because I created a test PHP file, it parses the <?php and runs the first thing inside the php tag, but the rest is ignored. I wrote this: "[...]<body><?php echo '<h2>Something</h2></br>';echo 'This';?>" and only the first echo is half run properly. Shows: Something (line break) then '"; echo 'This';?>"

Comment: i edited my answer try the code above and see if it runs...create a new project in your new install please...

Comment: I tried that, the php line gets commented out: '<!--<?php echo "hoja de pruebaaaaaa";?>-->'

Comment: mmm meaybe is a problem from your navigator change it after setting default all the stuffs in your xampp...did you configure something after your install in your xampp?if you did try to set as default and prove the code and we can disscard that is something that you are changing and the problem is you and no the machine jejeje let's try this ok?

Comment: Thank you for your help MickyScion. It seems to all be working now, I'm not sure which step worked. I did everything over once again, and something in that worked! Php is now working. Thanks a ton. If anyone else experiences these issues read the comments above and just follow the different steps, download XAMPP to a specific folder on your pc/server and keep testing.